# Windows 10 Game will not record chrome anymore

Tags: windows-10, xbox-game-dvr

I am using windows 10 and the built in Xbox Game DVR will nolonger record My web browser, Google Chrome.

Anyone have tips other than rebooting; I already tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding it to game list, second icon down in the Xbox app, top right add games and scroll down to google chrome.

Another option, press Windows Key and G while in Chrome and you may see a box with "Yes this is a game" option (or something like that!)

Comment: It fixed it self now but ill try that next time if it happens again!

Comment: the second option was the one that was failing for me

Comment: its not working anymore